# Using key function to add an element to an XML is not working using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, position, key

I am trying to work with the "key" function in XSLT to extract a value and add it at a particular position in XML. But I am not getting it right . Below is the input and XSLT.

Please help.

Input XML:

```
<input  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd">
            <info>User Info </info>
            <team>User Team </team>
            <nodeA id="test">
                <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
                <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
            </nodeA>
            <nodeA id="test2">
                <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
                <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
            </nodeA>
            <ns3:output xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org">
                <ns3:reply id="test">
                    <ns3:pkey>55555</ns3:pkey>
                    <ns3:place>SampleLoc</ns3:place>
                </ns3:reply>
                <ns3:reply id="test2">
                    <ns3:pkey>55557</ns3:pkey>
                    <ns3:place>SampleLoc2</ns3:place>
                </ns3:reply>
            </ns3:output>
        </input>
```

Expected Output:

```
<input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd">
        <info>User Info </info>
        <team>User Team </team>
        <nodeA id="test">
            <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
            <pkey>55555</pkey>
            <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
        </nodeA>
        <nodeA id="test2">
            <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
            <pkey>55557</pkey>
            <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
        </nodeA>            
    </input>
```

Given Below is my XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org"
        exclude-result-prefixes="soap xsl">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

        <xsl:key name="parKey" match="ns3:output/ns3:reply/ns3:pkey" use="/input/ns3:output/ns3:reply/@id"></xsl:key>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />                  
            </xsl:copy>     
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="/input">
            <xsl:variable name="output_186" select="ns3:output"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="./@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select=" * except $output_186"></xsl:copy-of>
            </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="/input//nodeA">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="./@*" />
                <pkey>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('parKey', @id)|." />           
                </pkey>                 
                <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="node()" />
            </xsl:copy>             
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is as below: Which is not showing my required field

```
    <input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"        
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd" >
        <info>User Info </info>
        <team>User Team </team>
        <nodeA id="test">
            <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
            <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
        </nodeA>
        <nodeA id="test2">
            <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
            <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
        </nodeA>
    </input>
```

Plese help me where exactly I am missing.

Thanks...

Comment: user1760178, You may be interested to see an even shorter solution that is both an XSLT 1.0 and an XSLT 2.0 one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shorter solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kpKeyByParentId" match="ns3:pkey" use="../@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="inodeAA">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kpKeyByParentId', ../@id)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ns3:pkey">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="ns3:output"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<input  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd">
    <info>User Info </info>
    <team>User Team </team>
    <nodeA id="test">
        <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
        <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
    </nodeA>
    <nodeA id="test2">
        <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
        <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
    </nodeA>
    <ns3:output xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org">
        <ns3:reply id="test">
            <ns3:pkey>55555</ns3:pkey>
            <ns3:place>SampleLoc</ns3:place>
        </ns3:reply>
        <ns3:reply id="test2">
            <ns3:pkey>55557</ns3:pkey>
            <ns3:place>SampleLoc2</ns3:place>
        </ns3:reply>
    </ns3:output>
</input>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd">
   <info>User Info </info>
   <team>User Team </team>
   <nodeA id="test">
      <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
      <pkey>55555</pkey>
      <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="test2">
      <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
      <pkey>55557</pkey>
      <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
   </nodeA>
</input>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every node for which it is selected for execution "as-is".
2. The ovveriding template that matches an `inodeAA` calls the identity template to copy itself, then applies templates on any `ns3:pkey` element, whose parent's `id` attribute has the same value as the `id` attribute of this `inodeAA` parent. For convenience and efficiency this is done by calling the `key()` function that references the `"kpKeyByParentId"` key, which defines an `ns3:pkey` as a function of the `id` attribute of its parent.
3. The template that matches an `ns3:pkey` element creates an element (in no namespace) whose name is the local-name of the matched element and also copies its contents.
4. The element `ns3:output` and its whole subtree is excluded from processing ("deleted") by a matching template that has an empty body.

Comment: its working......  I have got two answers... This community is rocking... I get lot of help....

Comment: @user1760178, You are welcome. I would recommend that whenever you have two correct answers, you prefer the shorter one -- as per the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing wrong is the "use" expression in your xsl:key. This should always be a relative path expression, relative to the node matched by the "match" pattern. I haven't worked out what it should be, because I haven't really worked out what you are trying to do. But I suspect it should be

```
match="ns3:reply" use="@id"
```

Comment: My case here is I have an XML which has got "input" and "output" as two main nodes under the root node.   Some data from "output" node is to be added to the "input" node and then the "output" node should be taken of the XML.     In the transformation I have used above I am successfully able to take away the "output" node, but not able to add the data part into the "input" node.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the tempplate which is working with the match="/input//nodeA"  is not at all happening. I have tried placing a <xsl:text> with some random text, even that text is also not printed in the XML.

Comment: I very carefully said "the most obvious thing wrong...". I was trying to make it clear that I had little confidence that when you fixed this, everything would work.

Answer (score 1):

The `use` attribute of `xsl:key` is a path relative to the element being matched, therefore you probably want

```
<xsl:key name="parKey" match="ns3:pkey" use="../@id"/>
```

in order to group `pkey` elements by the `id` attribute of their parent `reply` element.

But more generally your `/input` template is suspect:

```
    <xsl:template match="/input">
        <xsl:variable name="output_186" select="ns3:output"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="./@*" />
            <xsl:copy-of select=" * except $output_186"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
```

This is simply copying the entire source `input` element (minus the `ns3:output`), it is *not* recursively applying templates so the `nodeA` template that deals with the `pkey` will never fire.

Try something more like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="parKey" match="ns3:pkey" use="../@id"/>

    <!-- copy everything -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />                  
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- except ns3:output -->
    <xsl:template match="ns3:output" />

    <xsl:template match="nodeA">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            <xsl:element name="pkey">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('parKey', @id)" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>             
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It worked...... :) :)    As you said the /input is the culprit..  Thank you very much for your help.....